# Are all the WinterBash hats available on our beta site?

Tags: support, questions

I have been poking around here and Stack Overflow as I do normally during the work week and have been awarded some "hats" as part of [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/)

I have noticed that I earned a few different hats on Stack Overflow and Cross Validated, but only one hat on Bioacoustics even though that is my most active site.

This question is perhaps for mods/staff, but are all the Winter Bash hats available on beta sites, or just some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hats are fully available and alls sites! Its just most hats are harder to get on smaller sites like this one. For example, most active people cant suggest edits and take the tour and earn the informed badge. And Darkmode is only available on the SO sites. But you can still get some like Mmm, Cookies!, Behind the Curtain, and a bunch of others easily even on a small site.

Also, you can look [here](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/bioacoustics.stackexchange.com) for the leaderboard specific to Bioacoustics SE.